# How to get an ETA?

Tags: scons

I am build several large set of source files (targets) using scons. Now, I would like to know if there is a metric I can use to show me:

1. How many targets remain to be build.
2. How long it will take -- this to be honest, this is probably a no-go as it is really hard to tell!

How can I do that in scons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no progress indicator built into SCons, and it's also not trivial to provide one. The problem is, that SCons doesn't build the complete DAG first, and then starts the build...such that you'd have a total number of targets to visit that you could use as a reference (=100%).
Instead, it makes up the DAG on the go... It looks at each target, and then expands the list of its children (sources and implicit dependencies like headers) to check whether they are up-to-date. If a child has changed, it gets rebuilt by applying the same "build step" recursively.
In this way, SCons crawls itself from the list of targets, as given on the command-line (with the "." dir being the default), down the DAG...where only the parts are ever visited, that are required for (or, in other words: have a dependency to) the requested targets.

This makes it possible for SCons to handle things like "header files, generated by a program that must be compiled first" in the first go...but it also means that the total number of targets/children to get visited changes constantly.
So, a standard progress indicator would continuously climb towards the 80%-90%, just to then fall back to 50%...and I don't think this would give you the information you're really after.

Tip: If your builds are large and you don't want to wait, do incremental builds and only build the library/program you're currently doing work on ("scons lib1"). This will still take into account all dependencies, but only a fraction of the DAG has to get expanded. So, you use less memory and get faster update times...especially if you use the "interactive" mode. In a project with a 100000 C files total, the update of a single library with 500 C files takes about 1s on my machine. For more infos on this topic check out http://scons.org/wiki/WhySconsIsNotSlow .

Comment: I was afraid of this... Dammit! ^_~ Thank you.